# Using awk modify the column value if another column values matches a string

Tags: awk

I have the following output of a file:

```
host1|ip1|LCOS|
host2|ip2|Linux|
hos3|ip3|Linux|DiskStation Manager
```

where `$4` (`DiskStation Manager`) is set, `$3` should be changed to `DiskStation Manager`

I have tried the following but nothing changes

```
{ if( $4 ~ /DiskStation Manager/) $3=$4}
```

Comment: You forgot to print the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `~` when you know the string beforehand? You can do a literal string equality match. Also note that you have a typo in the match string, the `Station` has a uppercase `S`.

The below is simplified version of your attempt without an explicit `if` condition inside the `{..}` action part. The advantage of this would be to ignore processing *any* other lines *not* containing `$4` with your expected string. The `{..}1` would simply rewrite your line based on the modifications to column values and input/output field separators.

```
awk -v FS="|" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $4 == "DiskStation Manager" { $3 = $4 }1'
```

Or if you are going with the regex approach, put anchors around the string to have an exact match,

```
$4 ~ /^DiskStation Manager$/
```